# Accessing .eh_frame data during execution

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, c, glibc, elf

I'm trying to access the contents of `.eh_frame` section of a running program from within it (specifically, the program is Linux kernel 2.6.34.8). The `.eh_frame` contains useful data used for exception handling and I'd like to use it internally from within kernel code. The section is already being written by `gcc` (`readelf -a vmlinux.o` contains `.eh_frame`), the problem is reading it from the code. I'm pretty sure the elf format docs say that `.eh_frame` is accessible during code execution.

I've looked into the source of `glibc` in search of `.eh_frame` usage and found macros for most CFA instructions in `sysdeps/generic/sysdep.h`, but not the actual code that loads the `.eh_frame` data.

Is it required to modify the process of loading the kernel to load the data from the file, or is the `.eh_frame` info/`.eh_frame_hdr` section pointer stored somewhere as a macro/assembler name (so it can be extracted into a C variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vmlinux.o` is not the actual kernel that gets loaded.

The actual kernel image (typically `bzImage`) is not an ELF file and contains only the data needed for running the kernel.

Furthermore, most of the kernel is not compiled with exception handling information.

Comment: Thanks. But given a kernel compiled with exception handling information, is it (the `.eh_frame` data) possible to access it during runtime? If so, how?

Comment: As I said, that information might be in `vmlinux.o`, but is not in the actual kernel image.

Comment: So, to achieve the effect needed one would have to inject into the regular kernel build process, gather up all the `.eh_frame` data along with a symbol defined in the code that later on would be set to point at the newly created structed injected into the kernel image. The symbol would be then used to access the data gathered during runtime, right?

Comment: Yes, but why do you need exception information in the kernel, and in an outdated version like 2.6.34 at that?

Comment: An exercise given by one of my teachers :) Just wanted to make sure which steps of kernel build process I have to look closer into to make it possible to access the `.eh_data`. The data parsing part wouldn't be that hard as I've already tinkered with ELF files and using them to dynamically load libraries into a program. The 'join it all together, put into the image and set the defined name to point at the structure created' part looks like fun, and will definitely look into it.