# How to access .eh_frame section

Tags: gcc, abi

Since the contents of the `.eh_frame` section is used at runtime by the C++ library, I can only assume that is is mapped into the running process and that there is some way for the library to "get at it". Likewise, I can only assume that way is accessible outside the library as well, but how? Are there some symbols pointing to the relevant parts of it, and, if so, what names to they bear?

A very similar question was asked in [Accessing .eh_frame data during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091714/accessing-eh-frame-data-during-execution), but I would like to point out that it is not a direct duplicate, since it was asked in the context of the Linux kernel and was correctly answered in that that final compiled kernel does not include the `.eh_frame` sections. This question is about normal, userspace, ELF binaries.